# Icinga2 notifications

Tags: icinga2

I just looked at /etc/icinga2/features-enabled/notification.conf and saw,

> /**
>    * The notification component takes care of executing service checks.
>    */

Wouldn't that rather be the checker component?

Comment: Also, I'm never sure whether "notifications" includes alerts sent to icingaweb2.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong and should be fixed.

```
diff checker.conf notification.conf 
2c2
<  * The checker component takes care of executing service checks.
---
>  * The notification component takes care of executing service checks.
```